# PHPExcel writer too slow

Tags: phpexcel

I am generating a .xls file, in which there is a column containing formulas like these:

> IF(A1=1; 'xxx'; IF(A1=2; 'yyy'; IF(A1=3; 'zzz' ...

You know, it would be a SWITCH if it wouldn't be excel formula.

The problem is, depending on how many IF's I use, the time it takes to generate the .xls file grows exponentially.

The filesize is not much different.

I have 18 cases, which means 18 IF's and that takes just unacceptable amount of time.

Why is that so? Is there anything I might be doing wrong?

Here is a sample code:

```
for ($k = 1; $k<16; $k++){

    $cellID = "A".($row+$k);
    $codes_if = '=IF('.$cellID.'="1",4579,'
    .'IF('.$cellID.'="2",7978,'

    ... // some more IF's

    .'""))))))))))))))))';

    $actSheet->SetCellValue("B".($row+$k),$codes_if);

}
```

Comment: Suggest you replace your IF formula to use VLOOKUP or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formula like this with multiple nested IFs will be inefficient anyway

Consider replacing your multiple nested IFs with VLOOKUP instead

e.g.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,E1:F3,2,TRUE)
```

where column E contains the lookup values `1, 2, 3, ...` and column F contains the return values `aaa, yyy, zzz`, etc)

That is the equivalent of a switch statement in MS Excel

You will find that using VLOOKUP is a lot more efficient than your nested IFs

To reduce the time it takes to save the file further, be aware that PHPExcel calculates all formulae before saving ***by default***. You can change that behaviour by calling

```
$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
```

before calling the save

Comment: yep, came to the same conclusion shortly after I wrote the question. it did indeed solve my problem, even though I still would like to know why is it so slow with the IFs.

Comment: I didn't know that I could stop precalculating the formulas. That can be helpful.. thanks : )

Comment: If you want to know why nested ifs are so slow, the source is all there for you, or you could enable debug mode for the calculation engine (as described [here](https://gist.github.com/MarkBaker/5908357)) to see exactly what it's doing

Comment: Note that the PHPExcel Calculation Engine uses a simple stack based parser that has to calculate both possible values for an IF before testing the if condition itself, so nested IFs will become very expensive